# Publishing aws lambda version using jenkins and aws cli

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

I want to create a `jenkins` job that will publish a new `AWS lambda version` and update existing `alias` to new version just created.

I already have `prod` alias created in AWS Lambda.

Now i would i like to publish a new version and the update `prod` alias to point to new version.

There is [walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases-walkthrough1.html) shows how to do it using `AWS CLI`.  So here are the corresponding steps

1>Publish a new version of the Lambda function.
`aws lambda publish-version --function-name helloworld`

2>Update `prod` alias to latest version.
`aws lambda update-alias --function-name helloworld function-version 2 --name prod`

**ISSUE**
In Jenkins i will have to execute these commands as `windows batch command`
But i am not able to understand how do i dynamically pass the version number that was created by `publish-version` command in step 1, to `update-alias` command in step 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aws CLI command in the execute shell.

```sh
VERSION=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name helloworld | jq -r .Version)
aws lambda update-alias --function-name helloworld --name prod --function-version $VERSION
```